# specializing the selection inside database by particular order

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, xampp

your friend is a beginner in coding here,

i need your help for getting my desired  demand.

Actually, i'm creating my own inventory management system, and just stuck up with creating a condition in my php page for posting my recieved needs from the supplier.

i already made the html form to fill the product and it's item based in my structured database 'sql' including the recieved quantity,

when i press the selection of product the products is show the database inside the product table and it's working properly, but in the items selection the selection option show all the items, while all i want to condition the selection of items by referring to the selected product,

knowing that my tables in database has been relationed by an foreign key, in which the item is related to their product in the product table.

they told me that i should use ajax to create the selection items show by it's product, but as a beginner i did get the acknowledge to do it.

now i will give you my code to assist you in your help

mysql prevision database

```
first table : CREATE TABLE `stock_products` (
 `idstkproduct` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `idstksec` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `product_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` varchar(205) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;


Example odf the inserted data inside the first table :

 INSERT INTO `stock_products` (`idstkproduct`, `idstksec`, `product_name`, `description`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 2, 'super_star', 'non', '2024-01-26 17:45:24'),
(2, 1, 'darling', NULL, '2024-01-26 17:46:53'),
(4, 1, 'ruch', NULL, '2024-01-26 17:49:00'),
(5, 1, 'anita', NULL, '2024-01-26 17:49:00'),
(6, 1, 'x_tasy', NULL, '2024-01-26 17:49:00'),
(7, 1, 'africa_queen', NULL, '2024-01-26 17:49:00'),
(8, 3, 'elegance', NULL, '2024-01-26 17:52:06'),
(9, 3, 'magic-k', NULL, '2024-01-26 17:56:20'),
(10, 3, 'leila', NULL, '2024-01-26 17:56:20');  

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 second table: CREATE TABLE `stock_designation` (
 `idstkdesign` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `idstkproduct` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `designation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` varchar(205) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci; 

Example for the inserted data inside the 2nd table :
 INSERT INTO `stock_designation` (`idstkdesign`, `idstkproduct`, `designation`, `description`, `created_at`) VALUES
(1, 1, '1', 'noire couleur', '2024-01-26 18:18:03'),
(2, 1, 'white', 'white couleur', '2024-01-26 18:34:15'),
(3, 1, '950', 'couleur violet', '2024-01-26 18:34:15'),
(35, 2, '1', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:21:50'),
(36, 2, 'bleu', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:21:50'),
(37, 2, '613', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:21:50'),
(38, 2, '27', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:21:50'),
(39, 2, '350', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:21:50'),
(40, 2, '144', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:21:50'),
(51, 4, '1', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:39:31'),
(52, 4, '900', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:39:31'),
(53, 4, '33', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:39:31'),
(54, 4, '39', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:39:31'),
(55, 4, '27', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:39:31'),
(56, 4, '950', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:39:31'),
(75, 5, '1', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:46:59'),
(76, 5, '144', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:46:59'),
(77, 5, '33', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:46:59'),
(78, 5, 'night', NULL, '2024-01-29 13:46:59');


Now the relation code between the two tables : 

and now the relation between these two tables : ALTER TABLE `stock_designation`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idstkdesign`),
  ADD KEY `fk_stock_designation_stock_products` (`idstkproduct`);
```

supplier.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header('location: login.php');
$_SESSION['table'] = 'stock_products';
$_SESSION['redirect_to'] = 'product-add.php';
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Product - Inventory Management System</title>
    <?php include('partials/app-header-script.php');?>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dashboardMainContainer">
    <?php include('partials/app-sidebar.php')?>
    <?php include('./database/connection.php'); ?>

    <div class="dashboard_content_container" id="dashboard_content_container">
      <?php include('partials/app-topnav.php')?>
      <div class="dashboard_content">
        <div class="dashboard_content_main">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="column column-12">
              <h1 class="sectionheader"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create Arrived Marchandises</h1>
              <div id="useraddformcontainer">
               
<form method="post" action="purchase_script.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <h2>Purchase Transaction</h2>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Product Item</th>
        <th>Quantity Recieved</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="product_items">
      <tr id="row1">
        <td>
          <select name="product_id[]" id="product_id_1" required onchange="fetchDesignations(1)">
            <option value="">Select Product</option>
            <?php
                      // Retrieve products from the database (already in your code)
                      $sql = "SELECT idstkproduct, product_name FROM stock_products ORDER BY product_name ASC";
                      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                      $stmt->execute();
                      $products = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                      // Populate the dropdown with product options
                      foreach ($products as $product) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $product['idstkproduct'] . '">' . $product['product_name'] . '</option>';
                      }
                      ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="designation_id[]" id="designation_id_1" required>
            <option value="">Select Item</option>
               <?php
                      // Retrieve department names from the database (Code added here)
                      $sql = "SELECT idstkdesign, designation FROM stock_designation ORDER BY designation ASC";
                      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
                      $stmt->execute();
                      $designations = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                      // Populate the dropdown with Product options
                      foreach ($designations as $designation) {
                      echo '<option value="' . $designation['idstkdesign'] . '">' . $designation['designation'] . '</option>';
                      }
                      ?>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" min="1" required></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <button type="button" onclick="addRow()">Add Another Product Item</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Record entry</button>
</form>

                <?php if(isset($_SESSION['response'])) {
                  $response_message = $_SESSION['response']['message'];
                  $is_success = $_SESSION['response']['success'];
                  ?>
                  <div class="responsemessage">
                    <p class="responsemessage <?= $is_success ? 'responsemessage__success' : 'responsemessage__error'?>">
                      <?= $response_message ?>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                <?php unset($_SESSION['response']); }?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php include('partials/app-scripts.php');?>

</body>
</html>
```

designation.js

```
function fetchDesignations(productId) {
  // Use AJAX to send a request to fetch_designations.php
  $.ajax({
    url: "database/fetch_designations.php", // Ensure correct path
    method: "POST",
    data: { product_id: productId },
    success: function(response) {
      // Update the designation dropdown based on the response
      $("#designation_id_1").empty(); // Clear existing options
      $.each(response, function(index, designation) {
        $("#designation_id_1").append($("<option></option>").val(designation.id).text(designation.name));
      });
    } // Closing curly brace for the success function
  }); // Closing curly brace for the $.ajax call
} // Closing curly brace for the fetchDesignations function
```

```
fetch_designation.php
```

```
<?php
// Connect to the database (include your connection details)
// **Ensure the path to connection.php is accurate:**
require_once './database/connection.php'; // Adjust path if needed

// Check for database connection errors:
if (!$conn) {
    error_log("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    die("Database connection error"); // Or handle the error gracefully
}

if (isset($_POST['product_id'])) {
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    // Prepare and execute the query to fetch designations for the product
    $sql = "SELECT idstkdesign, designation FROM stock_designation WHERE idstkproduct = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$product_id]);

    // Fetch results as associative array
    $designations = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // **Debugging:** Check the fetched data before encoding:
    print_r($designations); // Or use var_dump($designations);

    // Encode the designations as JSON and send as response
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Set content type for JSON
    echo json_encode($designations);
}
?>
```

still the items selection shows all the item (not conditioned by my selected product), and i got frustrated to make it done,

i need your suggestion on what should i do, modify, or anything else to make my desired target accomplished

Comment: $sql = "SELECT idstkdesign, designation FROM stock_designation WHERE idstkproduct = " + $product_id;

Comment: `onchange="fetchDesignations(1)"` will always pass "1" as the parameter , See ?